# angularjs checkbox Incorrect response in console

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have two criteria:
1) Only allow one of two boxes selected at one time.
2) Capture the name of the box that is selected.

However, when I print out the list of checkbox objects they are correct, but when I check in the console they are not correct. For example,

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="treatment in treatment_list">
 <input type="checkbox" value="{{treatment.name}}"
        ng-model="treatment.checked"
        ng-click="updateTreatment($index, treatment_list);
                  checkedTreatment(treatment_list)">
 <label>Treatment {{treatment.name.toUpperCase()}}</label></input><br>
</div>
{{treatment_list}}
```

Controller:

```
$scope.treatment_list = [
    {
      name: 'a',
      checked: false
    }, {
      name: 'b',
      checked: false
    }
  ];

$scope.updateTreatment = function(position, treatment_list) {
    console.log(treatment_list);
    angular.forEach(treatment_list, function(treatment, index) {
      console.log(treatment.name, treatment.checked);
      if (position != index) {
        treatment.checked = false;
      }
    });
  };

$scope.$watch('treatment.checked', function (treatment) {
    console.log(treatment);
  });
```

Plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Hkb4IeKxi0TRqHRJA4JN?p=preview

Comment: use radio box instead

Comment: You're logging to the console before you set the value to false, that's why you are seeing both values as true. Also, that watch will never fire (or at least never after an initial digest cycle).

Answer (score 1):

Inorder to fullfill your requirement you should just use a radio box whith ng-model, it will work out of the box for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use radio buttons instead:

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
      $scope.color = {
        name: 'blue'
      };
      $scope.specialValue = {
        "id": "12345",
        "value": "green"
      };
      $scope.colorChange = function(color) {
          console.log(color);
      };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="red"
           ng-change="colorChange(color.name)" />
    Red
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" ng-value="specialValue"
           ng-change="colorChange(color.name)" />
    Green
  </label><br/>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" ng-model="color.name" value="blue"
           ng-change="colorChange(color.name)" />
    Blue
  </label><br/>
  <tt>color = {{color.name | json}}</tt><br/>
 </form>
 Note that `ng-value="specialValue"` sets radio item's value to be the value of `$scope.specialValue`.
</body>
```

For more infomation, see [AngularJS input type=radio Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D)